# Postgresql import user from linux

Tags: postgresql, authentication

I install postgresql 9.2 on a Ubuntu 12.10 machine

I tried to import linux's user to postgresql

but only way I can figure out is

```
CREATE USER Jack WITH PASSWORD '1234';
```

and do it 10 times (if there are 10 users)!!

Is there any faster way to do it?

Comment: OS authentication?

Comment: Just like users can use ubuntu's account to access postgresql database

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11949959/no-password-prompt-for-postgresql-superuser). You may also simply script 1..n users (all same password) and force a change on logging on [see here](http://www.dbforums.com/postgresql/927820-how-force-use-passwords.html)

Comment: Is there any way to force same password and username in ubuntu and postgres? I don't want make them to change their password again

Comment: But that's the whole point about OS authentication - the same process works for both.

Answer (score 1):

Postgres can hook into Linux's Pluggable Authentication Module (PAM), effectively "handing off the authentication process to any number of other providers.  One of these providers can be the local password file.

[Postgres and PAM](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/auth-pam.html) It's from the '11 Docs, but it's supported in 9.2.  Page includes a link to the Linux PAM documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try doing it from webmin. If you install the PostgreSQL module, under the postgres users section there is an option `Add a new PostgreSQL user when a Unix user is added`.